# Как ограничить область видимости карты, Map API Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Возможно ли как то ограничить область видимости, например квадрат на карте, за который нельзя выйти перемещением карты?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes the city of Adelaide in Australia.
private LatLngBounds ADELAIDE = new LatLngBounds(
  new LatLng(-35.0, 138.58), new LatLng(-34.9, 138.61));
// Constrain the camera target to the Adelaide bounds.
mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ADELAIDE);
```

более подробно на сайте
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#_14