# Работа с Google Maps API Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли способ используя Google Maps API под Android отображать только конкретную страну/город вместо всей карты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отключить отображение других стран невозможно.
можно ограничить область просмотра карты [Как ограничить область видимости карты, Map API Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693668/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-map-api-android/693687#693687)

Comment: Спасибо. А есть ли быстрый способ определить необходимые параметры для LatLngBounds(new LatLng(x1, y1), new LatLng(x2, y2));?